# Executing fabcar without fabric-ca

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I built a Fabric network with multiple orgs and tls enabled. Crypto material was built with cryptogen. I do not intend to use fabric-ca in my example.

I installed and instantiated fabcar through CLI. Invoke and Query with CLI commands work as charm.

Now, for the purpose of using nodejs scripts query.js and invoke.js I concatenated a private and public key in order to create PeerAdmin credential for Fabcar. I also altered a configuration in .js files to aim at peers and orderers with grpcs.

Whenever I execute any .js script, I am constantly getting the following error:

```
Create a client and set the wallet location
Set wallet path, and associate user  PeerAdmin  with application
Check user is enrolled, and set a query URL in the network
Caught Error Error: PEM encoded certificate is required.
    at new Endpoint (/home/hl/fabcar/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Remote.js:146:11)
    at new Remote (/home/hl/fabcar/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Remote.js:95:20)
    at new Peer (/home/hl/fabcar/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Peer.js:53:3)
    at Client.newPeer (/home/hl/fabcar/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Client.js:173:14)
    at Promise.resolve.then.then.then (/home/hl/fabcar/query.js:39:28)
    at <anonymous>
```

When I try to query the chaincode without grpcs I receive the following error:

```
Create a client and set the wallet location
Set wallet path, and associate user  PeerAdmin  with application
Check user is enrolled, and set a query URL in the network
Make query
Assigning transaction_id:  9cbf355cda03db2b1971fe10af27d66686ea9b913eda80f667cac48bada015bf
error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: Endpoint read failed
    at /home/hl/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:554:15
returned from query
Query result count =  1
error from query =  { Error: Endpoint read failed
    at /home/hl/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:554:15 code: 14, metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} } }
Response is  Error: Endpoint read failed
```

PeerAdmin content:

```
{"name":"PeerAdmin","mspid":"PeerOrgMSP","roles":null,"affiliation":"","enrollmentSecret":"","enrollment":{"signingIdentity":"[...]","identity":{"certificate":"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n[...]-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"}}}
```

Any help in pointing me to a right procedure or troubleshooting with the above would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are going to do a fabcar without a Fabric CA.
If so, you can't use the Node.js application because it is using user context and you didn't enroll user context.

But you want to use fabcar without CA, you can invoke or query transaction as cli.

1. connect to cli container, if you use fabcar, cli-container-name is 'cli' so

> docker exec -it cli bash

2. In cli container, you can invoke or query transaction. as the example below

> peer chaincode query -C mychannel -n fabcar -c '{"Args":["queryAllCars",""]}'
>
> peer chaincode query -C mychannel -n fabcar -c '{"Args":["queryCar","CAR4"]}'

invoking transaction is same

Answer (score 0):

When you enable gRPCs you must pass the pem as a parameter in the instantiation of the various Hyperledger element objects (e.g. peer, orderer). In the case of the fabcar example (`invoke.js`):

```
// This is a new line
var options = {                                                                 
    tls_cert: {                                                                 
        pem: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './network/tls') + '/peer.cert').toString(),
    }                                                                           
};                                                                              

...

// Replace the original instantiation by adding the pem option
var peer = fabric_client.newPeer('grpcs://fft-zbc03a.4.secure.blockchain.ibm.com:26268', {
    pem: options.tls_cert.pem                                                   
});                                                                             
channel.addPeer(peer);                                                          
// Replace the original instantiation by adding the pem option
var order = fabric_client.newOrderer('grpcs://fft-zbc03b.4.secure.blockchain.ibm.com:20161', {
    pem: options.tls_cert.pem                                                   
})                                                                              
...
// Replace the original instantiation by adding the pem option
event_hub.setPeerAddr('grpcs://fft-zbc03a.4.secure.blockchain.ibm.com:23972', {
    pem: options.tls_cert.pem                                                   
});
```

The code above assumes that you downloaded the right certificates to `network/tls/`. These certificates can be downloaded by sending requests to the CA. For a full example refer to the Bluemix documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-deploy-sample-application-ibm-blockchain-platform/index.html).